Auto recalculate special case, how to
I have a workbook with a worksheet containing my formulas. in that worksheet I have a named range in a cell called "FORMULA_VERMELL" containing the text "="TMP!A1"" (I plan to contain a more complicated formula in the future, of course)
In another worksheet called TMP, I have a value '123' in the cell A1
in another cell from TMP I am calling my custom vb function TextToFormula:
Public Function TextToFormula(cellRef As String)
    TextToFormula = Evaluate(cellRef)
End Function

... like this: =TextToFormula(FORMULA_VERMELL)
This converts a text containing a formula, into a real formula and evaluates it.
The problem is that if I change the value in A1 from '123' to another value, the cell containing the formula
=TextToFormula(FORMULA_VERMELL)
does not automatically change, as it is not directly referencing the A1 formula, but using the named range. So I have to edit the cell with F2+ENTER for it to recalculate.
Thanks in advance !

Insert into your function first line Application.Volatile

Or change the ref to Range.  Public Function TextToFormula(cellRef As Range) And then it should not need to be volatile.

...and TextToFormula = Evaluate(cellRef.Value)

I don't know the OP's exact use case, but this seems to be a facility to be able to refer to a complex formula via a Name, which is what LAMBDA provides. So possibly check that out (unless already discounted): https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67.

Application.Volatile did it, thanks. Now I am dealing with other related issues but I think I will succeed using this method, thank you !
